# Change href value of a link by fetching URL from JSON file (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json, href

I have a very simple .JSON file called 'screen.json' as follows:

```
[
    {
        "link": "http://localhost:8888/screen/screen1.png"
    }
]
```

And a very simple HTML link:

```
<a id="screen" href="#"></a>
```

What I would like to do is, on page load, using jQuery, fetch the "link" value from the .JSON file and put it inside the `href=""` tag where the # symbol is.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

}
```

I know it will involve an ajax call in the jQuery above, to get the string from the .json file and then place it inside the 'href=""' tag, but I don't know how to do this.

Could anyone help me? Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.get(url, function(response) {
       //response = JSON.parse(response);//use this in case you are not getting json in response to parse response
       //Change href Value use attr()
       $('#screen').attr('href', response[0]['link']); 
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked a treat, thank you very much for your help sir :)